# How to identify datapoints that drastically increase/decrease and make them NA? How to identify and nullify outliers?

Tags: r, for-loop, na, data-cleaning, outliers

I am cleaning data from multiple temperature sensors. I am trying to write code that will find places where the data drastically increased or decreased relative to the neighboring datapoint, and make that point NA/null.

I was trying to do this with a for loop and a couple of if statements, but there seem to be a few issues with this approach. Namely, the if statements don't really work with NA values. So if the first part of the loop makes one of the entries NA because it increased too much, the second part would return an error because it is trying to perform the operation with a NA entry.

I would prefer to make the outliers NA instead of deleting the entries, because I would like the option to replace the NA values with averages of the neighboring values later on.

Does anyone know of a different approach for identifying/nullifying data that changes too drastically/outlier data?

```
#maximum change per sampling interval 
c<- 1.5   
#make datapoints that increased/decreased too much from the previous datapoint NA
                for(x in 2: length(cleandata)){

                if((cleandata$tempdiff[x] - cleandata$tempdiff[x-1])>=c) cleandata$tempdiff<-NA
                if((cleandata$tempdiff[x-1]-cleandata$tempdiff[x])>=c) cleandata$tempdiff<-NA
                }
```

Here is a simplified piece of the dataset:

```
structure(list(TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1594911720, 1594911780, 
1594911840, 1594911900, 1594911960, 1594127280, 1594127340, 1594127400, 
1594127460, 1594127520, 1594127580), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), sensor = c("TempDiffs.1.", "TempDiffs.1.", "TempDiffs.1.", 
"TempDiffs.1.", "TempDiffs.1.", "TempDiffs.2.", "TempDiffs.2.", 
"TempDiffs.2.", "TempDiffs.2.", "TempDiffs.2.", "TempDiffs.2."
), tempdiff = c(10.45, 12.5, 10.52, 10.48, 10.48, 12.47, 12.48, 
12.49, 12.5, 12.52, 12.52)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), groups = structure(list(
    sensor = c("TempDiffs.1.", "TempDiffs.2."), .rows = structure(list(
        1:5, 6:11), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My other concern with this process is the transtiton between sensors. My data is formmatted to be long/tall. So there is one column identifying the sensor, and another column with the temperature data. Each sensor has a different "typical range" of temperatures. So, when switching from one sensor to the next, this code would probably nullify the data because it changes drastically. I figured one way to deal with this would be to group the data by the sensor column before nullifying the outliers. I would appreciate any suggestions about that!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data using `dput` or `structure` commands?

Comment: @HaciDuru absolutely, I just added a piece of the dataset to the post

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
c <- 1.5
d <- abs(cleandata$tempdiff[2:nrow(cleandata)] - cleandata$tempdiff[1:(nrow(cleandata)-1)])
d <- which(d > c)
cleandata$tempdiff[d] <- NA
d <- d + 1
cleandata$tempdiff[d] <- NA

> cleandata
             TIMESTAMP       sensor tempdiff
1  2020-07-16 11:02:00 TempDiffs.1.    10.45
2  2020-07-16 11:03:00 TempDiffs.1.    11.50
3  2020-07-16 11:04:00 TempDiffs.1.    10.52
4  2020-07-16 11:05:00 TempDiffs.1.    10.48
5  2020-07-16 11:06:00 TempDiffs.1.       NA
6  2020-07-07 09:08:00 TempDiffs.2.       NA
7  2020-07-07 09:09:00 TempDiffs.2.    12.48
8  2020-07-07 09:10:00 TempDiffs.2.    12.49
9  2020-07-07 09:11:00 TempDiffs.2.    12.50
10 2020-07-07 09:12:00 TempDiffs.2.    12.52
11 2020-07-07 09:13:00 TempDiffs.2.    12.52
```